# Asp.Net core ODATA compute property after filter

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

Is there any way to create a computed property on an ODATA HTTP request, after the ODATA filter has been processed?

I have the following model

```
class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string ImageLink { get; set; } //This is computed

}
```

And the following `IEdmModel`

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(app.ApplicationServices).EnableLowerCamelCase();

    var person = builder.EntitySet<Person>("People").EntityType;
    person.Property(x => x.Name);
    person.Property(x => x.Email);
    person.Property(x => x.ImageLink).IsOptional();

    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

The image link is generated dynamically and is a fairly costly process, as the link is signed. Is there a way to add only add this property when it is explicitly included by a `$select` and to only calculate after the filter is applied?

Setting the `Select(SelectExpandType.Allowed)` property does not seem to exclude it from the model.

I've managed to manually exclude the property by checking the query string in the controller. But the property is still included in the model, the value is null, and obviously this runs before any filter has applied.

```
var people = await _personService.FetchAllPeopleAsync(cancellationToken);
if (Request.Query.TryGetValue("$select", out var values) && 
    values.Any(v => v.Contains(nameof(Person.ImageLink))))
{
    return _photoService.AttachImageLinks(Url, people);
}

return people;
```